# disable foreign key check deleting InnoDB tables Perl Script

Tags: mysql, perl, scripting

Am fairly new to using MySQL and a total novice at Perl but am trying to hack someone elses script to help me out.  I got the script from [here](http://encodable.com/tech/blog/2009/07/09/MySQL_Drop_Multiple_Tables_From_a_Database).  It looks great so far but it fails as the tables have some foreign key check going on.  I could go through phpmyadmin and try and delete them all one by one but this takes for ever and is my third time of having to do this :(  My query is, can this script be ammended to include:

```
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

before it runs the drop table command?  I tried to follow the script through but could not find a definitive command part of the script (probably due to ignorance/lack of understanding).  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;

my $hostname = '';
my $database = '';
my $username = '';
my $password = '';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:${database}:$hostname",
  $username, $password) or die "Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $i = 0;
my @all_tables = ();
while(my $table = $sth->fetchrow_array)
{
  $i++;
  print "table $i: $table\n";
  push @all_tables, $table;
}
my $total_table_count = $i;

print "Enter string or regex to match tables to "
  . "delete (won't delete yet): ";
my $regex = <STDIN>;
chomp $regex;

$i = 0;
my @matching_tables = ();
foreach my $table (@all_tables)
{
  if($table =~ /$regex/i)
  {
    $i++;
    print "matching table $i: $table\n";
    push @matching_tables, $table;
  }
}
my $matching_table_count = $i;

if($matching_table_count)
{
  print "$matching_table_count out of $total_table_count "
    . "tables match, and will be deleted.\n";
  print "Delete tables now? [y/n] ";
  my $decision = <STDIN>;
  chomp $decision;

  $i = 0;
  if($decision =~ /y/i)
  {
    foreach my $table (@matching_tables)
    {
      $i++;
      print "deleting table $i: $table\n";
      my $sth = $dbh->prepare("DROP TABLE $table");
      $sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    print "Not deleting any tables.\n";
  }
}
else
{
  print "No matching tables.\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the foreign key's indefinitly, or just have them temporarily not check anything while you're working with the database?

Comment: (on a side note, the perl code could be: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;");$sth->execute`)

Comment: You can use `->do` in place of a prepare/execute pair if you're never going to use the prepared handle again :)

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I will give your ammendment a go when I pluck up the courage!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the [FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) to zero:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

...prior to the drop scripts will disable foreign key constraints instance wide.  Because you can have more than one catalog/database on a MySQL instance, this risks impacting anything else database-wise.

The general habit is to script these in order of key dependency, deleting/truncating data from parent tables before children.

Comment: how to set it back to the old value after execution of a bunch of SQLs? `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ?;`  Thanks!

Comment: `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Also, I believe this variable is session-based, so exiting mysql will also do the trick.  I'd still run the above to be sure though.

Comment: One very important note to make is that "Setting foreign_key_checks to 1 does not trigger a scan of the existing table data. Therefore, rows added to the table while foreign_key_checks = 0 will not be verified for consistency."  (via [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks))